# Do master-detail relationships not cascade their deletes?

Tags: master-detail, cascadedelete

I was under the impression that deleting a master record in a master detail relationship would delete the detail record automically, cascading the delete.

In practice I get this error

> DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete xxx could not be completed because it is associated with the following .: xxxx

I know lookups have the ability to cascade their deletes, but this isn't built in with master-detail relationships?

Edit: Leaving this downvoted post up in case any other person stumbles onto the same problem.

Essentially my issue is because the child object was a junction object meaning it had 2 master detail relationships. I think that is why the natural cascading behavior didn't delete this child object and threw an error.

Comment: Could you please add additional context on the relationships of the objects you are getting this error in?

Comment: How much more context is needed? It's when deleting the master record in a master detail relationship.The error displays the detail record in the error message

Answer (score 0):

*Custom* Master-Detail relationships reliably behave the same; they will delete the child records when the parent is deleted. *Standard* "master-detail" relationships, which many of which are technically a hybrid between lookup and master-detail, actually prevent deletion of the parent record. In those cases, you have to delete the child records before deleting the parent.

Comment: Why would this error display when both objects are custom and the relationship is custom?

Comment: @TemporaryFix Custom Lookup Fields (not master-detail) can restrict deletion of the parent when the child is present. Custom master-detail relationships always cascade delete.

Comment: Revisted this question and I think it was failing because the child object is actually a junction object. I think the other master detail relationship on it was preventing deletion.